# How can I add content:"NEW" to paragraphs 2 & 3 using only CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

1. help me put content="NEW" with css, but only in paragraf 2 and 3.
2. i mustn't change html code.
3. if possible pls wiht pseudo classes.

```
<div id="first-div">
  <h2>Subheading</h2>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p> <!-- i need to add content here-->
  <p>Paragraph 3</p> <!--and here -->
  <div id="second-div">
     <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
     <p>Paragraph 4</p>
     <p>Paragraph 5</p>
     <p>Paragraph 6</p>
     <p>Paragraph 7</p>
     <p>Paragraph 8</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the immediate child selector, also referred to as the child combinator (`>`), which will target only direct `p` children of `#first-div`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator):

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It
>   matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are
>   the direct children of elements matched by the first.

```css
#first-div>p::after {
  content: 'NEW';
  color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div">
  <h2>Subheading</h2>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p> <!-- i need to add content here -->
  <p>Paragraph 3</p> <!--and here -->      
  <div id="second-div">
    <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
    <p>Paragraph 4</p>
    <p>Paragraph 5</p>
    <p>Paragraph 6</p>
    <p>Paragraph 7</p>
    <p>Paragraph 8</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gnpkr7m/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#first-div > p::before {
  content : 'NEW ';
  color   : red;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div">
  <h2>Subheading</h2>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p> <!-- i need to add content here-->
  <p>Paragraph 3</p> <!--and here -->
  <div id="second-div">
     <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
     <p>Paragraph 4</p>
     <p>Paragraph 5</p>
     <p>Paragraph 6</p>
     <p>Paragraph 7</p>
     <p>Paragraph 8</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is first look at `#first-div` and drill down on its children using the direct descendant operator (`>`).

In case you need 2 specific elements, you can use the direct child operator along with the `nth-child` function.

```
#first-div > p:nth-child(2):after,
#first-div > p:nth-child(3):after {
  color: red;
  content: "NEW";
}
```

If you need all `p` tags under `#first-div`, just select all of them

```
#first-div > p:after {
  color: red;
  content: "NEW";
}
```